# Patterns of multi-tenant scalability

Tags: architecture, scalability, multi-tenant

I'm looking for some resources on patterns and best practices for scalability in software architecture which requires multi-tenancy in the following sense:

- Multiple user bases interacting with custom-configured (bespoke branding and feature-set) iterations of an application.

In an environment where several applications service different phases of the user's experience.

I'm really looking for general principles here, like approaches to standup, automation, tooling, and configuration, as they relate to scaling out to additional user bases/iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several viewpoints to be discussed as your question is in a very broad sense

1. Custom configuration

1.1 User Based

In case you are planning to allow the user's to custom configure the application, they have to be maintained on a per-user basis and in case of one user having access to different companies [tenants in Multi-Tenancy], you will also have to isolate the data by tenant and user combination

There are various levels like flipping switches by a user that turns on and off of a functionality to even licensing the product at a user level. The former will require a user based discretion alone. However, the latter one may require a workflow like a model where a user can raise a request for a feature from his admin and the admin approves the same and then the user gets to access the newly requested feature

1.2 Tenancy Based

In case of a tenancy based model of customization, there will be multiple levels like having a company [tenant] to subscribe to plans to gain access to the various application features.

Additionally, the tenant will have to configure the company workspace like providing the credit card details for payment, email configuration for the company specific emails etc. This also involves the flipping of ON / OFF switches which in turn make the functionality work more dynamically

2. Regarding the several applications you have plans for, they do require SSO and also the flow of the configuration and company specific data across the applications. There can be company [tenant] specific database which needs to be stored and maintained for which the Azure Shard Map or similar ones can be used
3. There is a code base scaling which can be configured on-demand by your PaaS provider like Azure. However, the application needs to be developed in a fashion so that it can support database partitioning and scaling. This will have to take into account the factors like data-isolation etc.

There are various PaaS providers which needs to be decided based on your exising and future / predicted user base and then the same can be decided and opted for.

Microsoft has some nice articles for Multi-Tenancy given below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430340.aspx

The sidebars also have bunch of links that help you in learning more and choosing the approach.

HTH

Comment: thank you, this is helpful. I'm looking more for what you called  "Tenancy Based" custom configuration, and principles of successfully building scalable systems which accommodate this. I'll read the two articles you linked. I appreciate the info.

Comment: These two links are unavailable now. The web archives for these links are:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170530080303/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20170201225118/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430340.aspx